# Returning a Array in Zapier

Tags: javascript, zapier

I have been trying to return data into zapier developer but even though the request returns an array it keeps failing. i have included the request and the sample response. Is there a way to return the array in the request code

```js
const options = {
  url: 'https://inventory.zoho.com/api/v1/salesorders',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  params: {
    'authtoken': bundle.authData.authtoken,
    'organization_id': bundle.authData.organization_id
  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results.salesorders 
    
  });
```

**Sample Request**

```
{
"code": 0,
"message": "success",
"salesorders": [
    {
        "salesorder_id": 4815000000044895,
        "customer_name": "Molly",
        "customer_id": 4815000000044080,
        "status": "fulfilled",
        "salesorder_number": "SO-00003",
        "reference_number": "REF-S-00003",
        "date": "2015-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "shipment_date": "2015-06-02T00:00:00.000Z",
        "shipment_days": 2,
        "quantity": 2,
        "quantity_invoiced": 2,
        "quantity_packed": 2,
        "quantity_shipped": 2,
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "total": 350,
        "bcy_total": 33,
        "created_time": "2015-05-28T23:37:00.110Z",
        "last_modified_time": "2015-05-28T23:53:31.110Z",
        "is_emailed": true,
        "is_drop_shipment": false,
        "is_backorder": false,
        "sales_channel": "direct_sales",
        "custom_fields": [
            {...}
        ]
    },
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

}

Comment: can you update your question with the error code you're seeing (and maybe a screenshot/description of where you're seeing it?)

Comment: @xavdid in the new Zapier Cli web builder. I have a array in my data but Zapier can't find it even when I do return results.deliveries;

Comment: sure, but what is the actual error message you're seeing? That will help clarify what the issue is.